# Another way of extending the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: set-theory

This question is kinda a follow-up on [Extending Banach-Tarski paradox?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261634/extending-banach-tarski-paradox)

On a sphere, we can do all kinds of translations. We will, as usual, look to the translations that are a string of two translations, $a$ and $b$, and their inverses, $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. We use the notation described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox). For simplicity, we ignore the identity element. So $S(a^{-1})$ are those who start in $a^{-1}$, and $S(a^{-1}a^{-1})$ are those who start in $a^{-1}a^{-1}$. The normal Banach-Tarski paradox now says that $S(a)$ and $aS(a^{-1})$ together form a sphere.

---

**What I want to know:**

- Do $S(aa)$ and $aaaS(a^{-1}a^{-1})$ form a sphere together?

---

I know I can just repeat making two spheres out of one, but I'm just curious whether this will work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you need the axiom of choice? Do you think the axiom of choice is needed only because you cut the sphere into five parts?

Comment: No, I meant using AC for cutting the sphere itself, not for applying it to all points at once. I will clarify that, thank you.

Comment: Since the crux of the "paradox" is that you cut it into non-measurable sets, let me ask again, why wouldn't you need it? It's also unclear whether or you are asking about cutting the sphere into infinitely many pieces at once, or just repeating the process infinitely many times?

Comment: I ask for doing it at once. Further, when I normally cut the sphere in five parts, I don't need AC. I only need AC to do it for every point on the sphere. That is what I mean.

Comment: [Have you looked here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Obtaining_infinitely_many_balls_from_one) before asking?

Comment: Also I don't understand the statement that "Further, when I normally cut the sphere in five parts, I don't need AC. I only need AC to do it for every point on the sphere.", there are models of $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$ where the Banach-Tarski theorem fails. Period. You cannot cut the sphere into five, or nine, or $42$ parts and using measure preserving maps create two, or six or hundred copies of the unit ball. Period. You need to appeal to the axiom of choice when you do *the usual normal standard* Banach-Tarski proof. So I really have no idea what you mean by that statement.

Comment: Regarding the link: No, I haven't seen that, but it doesn't answer my question specifically. Regarding the AC thing: Given a certain point on the sphere, I can cut the sphere in a finite number of parts, or did I completly misunderstood Banach-Tarski? I am a beginner at set theory.

Comment: What does the point matter? Who cares about the point?

Comment: I've removed the question about the Axiom of Choice, but I'd still like to know whether this method is valid or complete nonsense.

Comment: I think that you should reformulate your question(s). As they are written I do not understand what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @user126154 I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The notation described in this question actually differs from the [usual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) one: $S(w)$ is usually used for those words which *start* with $w$, rather than those which *end* in $w$. For the rest of my answer, I'll assume the standard one was intended to be used; if this is not the case, rest of my answer might be moot.

If $S$ denotes the whole sphere, including identity element $e$, we have 
$$aaS(a^{-1}a^{-1})\cup S(a)=S$$ since any element starting with $a$ belongs to $S(a)$ and any element not starting with $a$ can be translated by $a^{-1}a^{-1}$ to become member of $S(a^{-1}a^{-1})$. Subsequent translation by $aa$ transforms it back to its original form.

Translating the equality by $a$ yields
$$aaaS(a^{-1}a^{-1})\cup aS(a)=aS$$
which can be simplified as 
$$aaaS(a^{-1}a^{-1})\cup S(aa)=S$$
since translation by $a$ is an automorphism of $S$.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good answer, considering to give the bounty to you.

Comment: However, can you tell why $aS(a)=S(aa)$? It doesn't seem to work on $aaaS(a^{-1}a^{-1})=S(aaaa^{-1}a^{-1})=S(a)$, because $S(a) \cup S(aa) \neq S$

Comment: $S(x)$ is a tricky construct -- it actually contains two requirements, not just one. the first one is easy: the words in $S(x)$ need to start with $x$. The second one says that the remainder of the word, after the initial $x$, cannot start with inverse of last "letter" of $x$. As long as we avoid touching the last letter of $x$, we can move the letters to and from $S(x)$ freely; this second requirement is maintained. Thus, $aaaS(a^{-1}a^{-1})=aaS(a^{-1})$. However, the next step would affect the last remaining letter and thus break the second requirement.